# Save user image url in database

Tags: php, database, laravel

I save the image in the public folder but i need the image url saved in the database instead of the file name.

https://devdojo.com/episode/laravel-user-image

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request){

      if ($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request ->file('avatar');



        $fileName = time().'.'. $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/'. $fileName));

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $fileName;
        $user->save();

      }
      return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    }
```

Comment: it is recommended not to store paths in DB as they can change or if domain change etc. then it will be hard to change all the paths in DB. Better to keep the path in .env or config file and keep the image name in DB

Comment: What do you mean "get it from the mobile app" ? You need to serve the images from your web server.

Answer (score 2):

It is highly not recommend to use that approach, instead save the name in database, and use the file path with the name on the database to display the image.

For example:

`<img class="border-radius-3" src="{{ asset('uploads/avatars/'.$user->image)}}" alt="">`

Just tell us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is the correct answer - save the filename (or determine the filename from the model's primary key, or something similar). This way you have control over the domain name (you can change it, put it behind a CDN, etc). In addition other answers like base 64 encoding the image won't scale.

Comment: You're right but I'm already saving the name in the database but i thought that saving the path or the url as a string in the db would be easier and safer for reuse it in other situations

Answer (score 1):

If you need save file URL in DB you can use something like this

```
 $user->avatar = '/uploads/avatars/'.$fileName);
```

Comment: It would generally be best to leave off the domain, i.e. `$user->avatar = 'uploads/avatars/'.$fileName);`, and let Laravel handle that by using the `url()` helper, i.e. `<img src="{{ url($user->avatar) }}">`. That way if the domain changes in the future the images don't all break.

Comment: @ceejayoz Agreed. Much better. Will fix the answer

Answer (score -2):

You should convert img to base64 to store it as a string in DB.

I never recommend this, but anyway:

```
$data = base64_encode($img);
```